# Proving a log by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, logarithms

I had a test recently and there was a log question that was $$3\log_3(x) - 4\log_3(x) + 1/2\log_3(x).$$ When I solved it I got $$\log_3 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right).$$ My teacher says that is incorrect, so I asked many people and they said I was correct. She said the only way I could get points back was if I prove it by induction, which I do not know what that is. I was wondering if my answer was right and if so how would I prove it by induction if thats possible? Thanks for all your help. Its critical I get these points back

Comment: It would be good if you could show your work.  What answer did the teacher give?

Comment: Either you are kidding us or the people who told you about induction were kidding you.

Comment: And more over, what was $exactly$ the question? From my understanding it looks like "condense into one logarithm" for which no induction is needed.

Comment: Your teacher's wrong. Your answer is right and induction has nothing to do with it. If the teacher won't budge then complain to someone with more authority.

Comment: I would guess your teacher has the answer as $-\frac{1}{2}\log_3(x)$ and didn't realize it is the same answer....

Comment: She did not have that @N.S.

Comment: @Aretino I am pretty sure she is kidding me because I do not know what that is and is saying that because I can't do it

Comment: @user84413 her answer was log3(1/x^1.5)

Comment: If the problem was to simplify the expression you have written, then this answer is not correct (and yours is, as Qiaochu Yuan and Michael Hardy have said).  You can try substituting $x=9$ to see that this answer is not right.

Comment: I have done that and showed her however she said you can't use real values until you prove through induction which is why I was asking. I understand that induction is unnecessary for this problem, but is it even possible? If it is, how could you do it? @user84413

Comment: No, induction isn't relevant to this problem, as Michael Hardy indicates.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help @user84413

Comment: Because induction does not apply, how could I prove that log a - log b + log c = log ac/b. @user84413

Comment: You can use the laws of logarithms to get log a - log b + log c=(log a + log c)-log b=log(ac)-log b=log(ac/b).

Answer (score 1):

Shifting the powers, you get:

$$ \log_3(x)^3 - \log_3(x)^4 + \log_3(x)^.5 $$
$$ =  \log_3( x^3 / x^4) + \log_3(x)^.5
$$
$$ = \log_3 \frac 1 x + \log_3(x)^{0.5}
$$ $$ = \log_3 \frac 1 x \cdot x^{0.5}$$
$$= \log_3 \frac 1 {x^{0.5}} == \text{CORRECT!}  $$

Edit: Saw wrong question. OP answer was correct after all

Comment: I don't think one should write $=\text{CORRECT}$.  The expression preceding $\text{“}=\text{''}$ is not equal to something called "CORRECT". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy how about  == ?

Comment: This is what I had but she says its incorrect. How can i prove it is correct? She said I have to prove it through induction. I am unsure what that is

Answer (score 1):

$$
3\log_3(x) - 4\log_3(x) + \frac 1 2 \log_3(x)
$$

What is written above does not express any math problem, **but** if you had said that some **words** above it say **"Write this as a single logarithm."**, then you'd have a math problem to work on.  (One of the flaws (or worse than flaws) of our system of coercing masses of people to learn topics in mathematics whose reason for inclusion in the curriculum is only that they're used in later subjects that most students never take is that they have these strange distorted ways of thinking (if "thinking" it may be called) in which students think that what is written above expresses a problem even when no words accompany it.)

Now notice that it says
$$
3 L - 4L + \frac 1 2 L.
$$
You can do that because the three $\text{“}L\text{''}$s are all the same: all three are $\log_3 x$.

Next, the distributive law is
$$
\left( 3 - 4 + \frac 1 2\right) L.
$$
Arithmetic tells us that this is
$$
\frac{-1}2 L.
$$
All of that is done **without knowing anything about logarithms.** But the next step requires some knowledge of logarithms:
$$
\frac{-1} 2 \log_3 x = \log_3 (x^{-1/2}).
$$
If it had said "Write this expression as a single logarithm", then we're done with that.

Knowledge of exponents tells us that $x^{-1/2} = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt x}$.  Hence the expression we're trying to write a just one logarithm is
$$
\log_3 \frac 1 {\sqrt x}.
$$

Induction is not an appropriate technique for any of this.

Comment: thank you for this. My teacher is not very smart. I think she just said that because we do not know what that is. Thanks for this

Comment: By showing this to her, would I prove that my answer is correct?

Comment: @Ryan : Perhaps you would.  One qualm I have is the possibility that you misunderstood what your teacher said and consequently we don't really have that story.  But your other theory --- that she tried to pull the wool over your eyes, is also something that happens. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Micheal Hardy I can tell you that I did understand what she said. She did the problem a little different. She did the addition part of the problem first and then applied that to the subtraction. Making it log3(1/x^1.5). I know that is incorrect and the only way it could be correct is if there were parentheses which there was not

Comment: @MichealHardy Because induction does not apply, how could I prove that log a - log b + log c = log ac/b.

Comment: @Ryan : Induction can be used to prove that $\log a_1 + \cdots + \log a_n$ $=\log(a_1\cdots a_n)$ provided you've already got $\log a + \log b = \log(ab)$, but you don't need anything as strong as that for the present problem.  $(\log a - \log b) + \log c$ $= \log\dfrac a b + \log c$ $=\log \dfrac{ac} b$.  You're just applying each of two basic identities once. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: is it possible to prove the original log and the condensed log are equal for all (n) values through induction